# If $A$ and $B$ are two matrices such that $AB=B$ and $BA=A$ then how to show that $A^2+B^2$ equals $A+B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

> If $A$ and $B$ are two matrices such that $AB=B$ and $BA=A$ then  $A^2+B^2$ equals ?
>
> (a) $2AB$
>
> (b) $2BA$
>
> (c) $A+B$
>
> (d) $AB$

I tried 
$(A+B)^2=A^2+B^2+AB+BA$

or,$A^2+B^2=(A+B)^2-AB-BA$

$=(A+B)^2-A-B$

$
=(A+B)^2-(A+B)=(A+B)(A+B-1)$

How to reach the answer from here?

Comment: You got your answer. Would like to point out though that at the last line there should be $I$ instead of $1$.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, here is how you can figure out the answer by process of elimination. We can see that if $A$ and $B$ are both identity, then the condition is satisfied, and $A^2 + B^2 = 2I$ in that case. This rules out option (d). Next, note that $A^2 + B^2$ is symmetric in $A$ and $B$, so if (a) were correct, then by symmetry (b) must be correct also. So that leaves (c).

Now, this doesn't establish that (c) is actually correct. To solve the problem properly, note that

$$A = BA = (AB)A = A(BA) = A^2$$,

and similarly $B = B^2$. Thus, $A^2 + B^2 = A + B$.

Comment: For an explicit example of such, one can take $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0 \\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\0&1  \end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

More precisely, there is a positive integer $p$ s.t. $A,B$ are simultaneously similar to $A'=\begin{pmatrix}I_p&0\\0&0_{n-p}\end{pmatrix},B'=\begin{pmatrix}I_p&Q\\0&0_{n-p}\end{pmatrix}$ where $Q$ is an arbitrary $(p\times n-p)$ matrix.

Proof. Since $A^2=A$, there is $p$ s.t. $A$ is similar to $A'=\begin{pmatrix}I_p&0\\0&0_{n-p}\end{pmatrix}$; let $B'=\begin{pmatrix}P_p&Q\\R&S_{n-p}\end{pmatrix}$. Then just proceed with identification in the relations $A'B'=B',B'A'=A'$.

Comment: $A$ is a matrix, not as a linear transformation. So you can't just say there is a basis such that $$A=\begin{pmatrix}I_p&0\\0&0_{n-p}\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @ TonyK , you are right; I edit...